# Running geth test node returns bash: /geth.ipc: Permission denied

Tags: go-ethereum, testing

I am trying to run a geth test node as shown [here](http://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_mist.html) in the tutorial but when i run the command `geth --ipcpath <test-chain-directory>/geth.ipc --datadir <test-chain-directory> --dev console` ( in test-chain-director i used a directory i created for this project) returns  `bash: /geth.ipc: Permission denied`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace <test-chain-directory> with the actual path to the directory you're using as `datadir`.

Comment: I already did that. i created a folder in my docs and used `<~/Documents/GethDev>`

Comment: Get rid of the brackets.